# Interior relation

Tags: general-topology

Let $f$ be a convex function from $C$ a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. How to prove that $$\operatorname{int}(f(C)+\mathbb{R}^m_+)=f(C)+\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}^m_+)$$

I need help for the direct inclusion $\subset$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in$ Int $(f(C)+R_+^m) $, let $x=f(c)+y$ with $c\in C$ and $y\in R_+^m.$

For some $r>0$ we have $B(x,r)=B(f(c)+y,r)\subset f(C)+R_+^m.$

Let $0<r'\leq r$ where $r'$ is less than the least co-ordinate of $y.$ Then $B(y,r')\subset$ Int $(R_+^m ). $ Therefore  $x\in B(x,r')=B(f(c)+y,r')=f(c)+B(y,r')\subset f(C)+$ Int $(R_+^m.)$

Observe that we can replace $f(C)$ with any $T\subset R^m$ to get  Int$ (T+R_+^m)\subset T+$ Int $(R_+^m).$

Comment: Thank you user254665. I am going to see your approach in details.